# dig-like functionality on windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, perforce, dig

On a windows system, I'm trying to gather all the IP addresses for a DNS name & call a tool with each IP address.  I know how to do it from a shell script - but not how to do it from a batch or powershell file.

I want to port this to windows..

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Get all the IPs for our server instance
# and pass it to "p4 trust" to update the .p4trust file
for address in $(dig perforce.example.com +short)
do
    echo "processing address: $address:1666"
    p4 -p "ssl:$address:1666" trust -y -f || true
done
```

Questions:

1. is there a pre-installed windows `dig` equivalent that will only return the IPs of the DNS record?
2. in a batch or powershell file, how do you iterate over multiple results from another application?

Comment: foreach in powershell. you have nslookup and resolve-dnsname. dont use batch. its 2019 after all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this...

```
Get-Command -Name Resolve-Dns* | 
Format-Table -AutoSize

CommandType Name                   Version Source       
----------- ----                   ------- ------       
Cmdlet      Resolve-DnsName        1.0.0.0 DnsClient     

# Get parameters, examples, full and Online help for a cmdlet or function

(Get-Command -Name Resolve-DnsName).Parameters
Get-help -Name Resolve-DnsName -Examples
Get-help -Name Resolve-DnsName -Full
Get-help -Name Resolve-DnsName -Online


# Get all IPAddresses for the provided DNS name
$env:USERDNSDOMAIN | ForEach{Resolve-DnsName -Name $PSItem}

Name          Type   TTL   Section    IPAddress                                
----          ----   ---   -------    ---------                                
CONTOSO.COM A      600   Answer     192.168....                             
CONTOSO.COM A      600   Answer     10.10... 

# 
$env:USERDNSDOMAIN | 
ForEach{
    # Get all IP addresses for the provided DNS name
    $DNSIPA = (Resolve-DnsName -Name $PSItem).IPAddress
    
    # Check if the host is up for a given IPA and port number
    ForEach($IPA in $DNSIPA)
    {
        "Processing $IPA"
        Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $IPA -Port 1666
    }
}
```

Yet, this question would translate into you are new to PowerShell. So, before you cause yourself undue confusion/frustration, etc., it is vital you spend the time getting up to speed on it using all the available free PowerShell video and eBook training resources. Here are just a few.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/getting-started-with-windows-powershell?view=powershell-6), [MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/), [MVA](https://mva.microsoft.com/training-topics/powershell#!lang=1033), [MSChannel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Search?term=powershell&lang-en=true), [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beginning%20powershell), [eBooks](https://leanpub.com/u/devopscollective), use the help files as noted above.

Comment: Nice!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you @postanote!

Comment: No worries. Glad it will help. Just a note. Test-NetConnection is not in all versions of PowerShell and dependent on the OS you are on. If you are not on a PowerShell / OS version that has this cmdlet, you'll need to resort to the .Net TCPClient namespace to do this sort of thing, well, for the port check stuff. For Example: https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/scanning-ports