# External -IP Loadbalancer aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I run a LoadBalance on aws and when I tried to get an external ip i got like this:

```
a86a863a4bea9807-1478376474.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
```

Is it possible to get a normal IP?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can get the IP, e.g. using `dig` or `drill` commands:

```
drill a86a863a4bea9807-1478376474.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
```

But the IP returned are **not static IP** addresses. If you require to have static IP addresses for your load balancer, you should use either Network Load Balancer, or add [global accelerator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/latest/dg/about-accelerators.alb-accelerator.html) to Application Load Balancer.

Comment: @AlexWhite What do you mean by windows 10? Your question did not include any information about your windows 10.

Comment: When I type kubectl get svc, i get my service (loadbalancer) with external ip, and the ip has the type above.

Comment: @AlexWhite You haven't specified your OS so I assumed that you use the most popular OS on AWS, which is Linux. You write the command in linux terminal.

Comment: Is there smth for windows as well?

Comment: @AlexWhite Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54175952/dig-like-functionality-on-windows) for `dig`  functionality on windows.